# Java Rock Paper Game Loops Too Many Times

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I had to make a rock paper scissors game, where you play against the computer. 1,2,3 are used for rock, paper, scissors.It loops 5 times, and shows the amount of computer wins and player wins. I got everything to work, except for the looping. When you put a number higher than 3, it's suppose to say "Invalid" and loop until you play 5 valid games. However if you you put an odd amount of wrong answers, it makes you play 6 games, and if you put an even amount of wrong answers, it makes you play 5 games. I need it to make you play 5 games regardless of odd and even amounts wrong. Please help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int player = 0, computer = 0;
    int computerScore = 0, playerScore = 0;
    int loops = 0;

    int rock = 1;
    int paper = 2;
    int scissors = 3;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {


        computer = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors");
        player = reader.nextInt();


        if (player > scissors) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid response");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors");
            player = reader.nextInt();
            i--;

        }


        if (player == computer) {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        } else if (player == rock) {

            if (computer == paper) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Paper, Computer wins");
                computerScore++;
            } else if (computer == scissors) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Scissors, Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            }
        } else if (player == paper) {

            if (computer == rock) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Rock , Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            } else if (computer == scissors) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Scissors, Computer wins");
                computerScore++;
            }
        } else if (player == scissors) {
            if (computer == rock) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Rock , Computer wins");
                computerScore++;
            } else if (computer == paper) {
                System.out.println("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Paper, Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            }

        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Computer Wins " + computerScore);
    System.out.println("Player Wins " + playerScore);

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think the line `i--;` inside the first `if` block is doing?

Comment: its so the loop repeats 5 times still if you get it wrong, cause you have to play 5 games.

Comment: But you're re-reading the input within the same iteration of the loop.  So why do you need to reset the counter?

Comment: You are close - everything you need is to polish your code. Nevertheless, I suggest you to write the another class or even better _enum_ for your game. Also, it would be easier to use **try-catch** for invalid user input.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier, I suggest using a while loop.

E.G:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
int computerScore = 0, playerScore = 0;

int rock = 1;
int paper = 2;
int scissors = 3;
int numberOfPlayerTurns = 0;

final int MAX_PLAYER_TURNS = 5;
while (numberOfPlayerTurns < MAX_PLAYER_TURNS)
{
    int computer = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    int player = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors");

    // invalid
    if (player > scissors || player <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Not a valid response");
    }
    else
    {
        numberOfPlayerTurns++;

        if (player == computer) 
        {
            System.out.println("Tie");
        }
        else if (player == rock ) 
        {
            if(computer == paper)
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Paper, Computer wins");
                computerScore++;
            }    
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Scissors, Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            }
        }
        else if (player == paper) 
        {
            if(computer == rock)
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Rock , Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Scissors, Computer wins");
                 computerScore++;
            }
        }
        // scissors
        else
        {
            if(computer == rock)
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Rock , Computer wins");
                computerScore++;
            }    
            else
            {
                System.out.println ("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Paper, Player wins");
                playerScore++;
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Computer Wins " + computerScore);
System.out.println("Player Wins " + playerScore);
```

Comment: Nice try. I won't down-vote, but did you even try to run your code? I'm asking you to test it - you will be surprised with some inputs...

Comment: @zlakad Thanks, no I didn't. Updated my answer, was missing a case for player == scissors.

Comment: You need points for reputation, so I'll up-vote your answer (I'd code it different, but here you are).

Comment: the while loop works, but it loops forever and doesnt computer the amounts won for player and computer after 5 rounds.

Comment: This does not handle the scenario when the user enters an invalid input