# How to make an if statement with multiple variables and multiple conditions into a switch case ? Can && compare cases?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, logical-operators

I'm making a rock paper scissors game for school and I have a working game but its 213 lines long. I was trying to shorten it up some by adding switch case in place of my if statements. Are there some instances where a switch case just won't work and it has to be an if statement?

```
String weaponChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
switch (weaponChoice) {
    case "Rock":
        System.out.println("You Chose Rock");
        break;
    case "Paper":
        System.out.println("You Chose Paper");
        break;
    case "Scissors":
        System.out.println("You chose Scissors");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println(weaponChoice + " is not a valid answer the computer gets a point!");
        compScore++;
        break;
}
```

I had the above code in an if statement and switched it over no problem but the below code I'm not sure how to change it over.

```
String getComputerChoiceVariable = getComputerChoice();
System.out.println("The computer chose " + getComputerChoiceVariable);

if (weaponChoice.equals(getComputerChoiceVariable)) {
    System.out.println("It's a draw!");
    ties++;
} else if ((weaponChoice.equals("Rock")) && (getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Scissors"))) {
    System.out.println("You won!");
    userScore++;
} else if ((weaponChoice.equals("Paper")) && (getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Rock"))) {
    System.out.println("You won!");
    userScore++;
} else if ((weaponChoice.equals("Scissors")) && (getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Paper"))) {
    System.out.println("You won!");
    userScore++;
} else if (weaponChoice.equals("Rock") && getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Paper")) {
    System.out.println("You Lost!");
    compScore++;
} else if (weaponChoice.equals("Paper") && getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Scissors")) {
    System.out.println("You Lost!");
    compScore++;
} else if (weaponChoice.equals("Scissors") && getComputerChoiceVariable.equals("Rock")) {
    System.out.println("You Lost!");
    compScore++;
}
```

Maybe something like

```
switch (weaponChoice,getComputerChoiceVariable){
    case "Rock",case "Scissors":
        System.out.println("You won!");
}
```

But Java doesn't like that I get a ton of errors. Can a switch take two parameters? 
I'm super new to Java.
Could I somehow use the && to compare cases?

Comment: [This can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211303/java-rock-paper-game-loops-too-many-times/52227834#52227834)

Comment: Tip: Post your current working code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), we can suggest improvements over your working program.

Comment: You can switch based on only one condition. However you can embed switch in another switch (usually ends up very unreadable, but doable).  `switch (computerWeapon){case "whatever":switch(userWeapon){case...` Not recommended.

Comment: Use a nested switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `switch` statement can test the value of only one expression.  It is possible to nest `switch` statements, but that's overly verbose and is no better than a series of `if`/`else` statements.

As an aside, you may want to validate the user's weapon of choice, so someone doesn't choose Lizard, Spock, Foo, or something else unexpected.

You can concatenate the strings into one so it can be tested.  I would use a separator such as `"|"` to make the choices clear.  Also, different cases have the same logic, avoiding repetition.

```
switch(weaponChoice + "|" + computerChoice)
{
    case "Rock|Scissors":
    case "Scissors|Paper":
    case "Paper|Rock":
        System.out.println("You won!");
        userScore++;
        break;
    case "Rock|Paper":
    case "Paper|Scissors":
    case "Scissors|Rock":
        System.out.println("You lost!");
        compScore++;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("It's a draw!");
        ties++;
}
```

This is concise and it lists all similar cases together, without repetition.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. I know that || means or what does | mean in java? is that just sorta like a place holder that will separate the rock Scissors? how does it work with out me typing in Rock| or Scissors|

Comment: In this code it is just a String separator for humans, for easier readability. For the computer is does not matter.

Comment: By itself `|` means "bitwise or".  But here, I'm just using the character in a string as a visual separator.  There's no bitwise-or-ing going on here; just a concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 0):

A switch block cannot be written with two parameters. From Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

However, you could make your program more modular by writing:

```
if (weaponChoice.equals(getComputerChoiceVariable)) {
  System.out.println("It's a draw!");
  ties++;
} else if (userWins(weaponChoice, getComputerChoiceVariable)) {
  System.out.println("You won!");
  userScore++;
} else {
  System.out.println("You Lost!");
  compScore++;
}
```

and using something like:

```
public boolean userWins(String userWeapon, String compWeapon) {
  if((userWeapon.equals("Rock")) && (compWeapon.equals("Scissors"))) {
      return true;
  } else if((userWeapon.equals("Paper")) && (compWeapon.equals("Rock"))){
      return true;
  } else if((userWeapon.equals("Scissors")) && (compWeapon.equals("Paper"))){
      return true;
  } else if(userWeapon.equals("Rock") && compWeapon.equals("Paper")) {
      return false;
  } else if(userWeapon.equals("Paper") && compWeapon.equals("Scissors")) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `userWins` could return a single boolean expression. Also, you declared it as `void`, should be `boolean` (this is just a nitpick).

Answer (score -2):

You don't necessarily need to make a switch of your code to shorten it. You can put the tree options in a list, and compare the user's choice with the value that that comes after the computer's choice to see if the user won.

If you have the list `[Rock, Paper, Scissors]`, the computer chose Rock. Find the element after it, so Paper in this case. Now you only have to see if that value is equal to the user's choice, and if that's the case, the user won.

```
List<String> choices = Arrays.asList("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors");

if (playerChoice.equals(computerChoice)) {
    System.out.println("Draw!");
} else if (playerChoice.equals(choices.get((choices.indexOf(computerChoice) + 1) % 3))) {
    System.out.println("You won!");
} else {
    System.out.println("You lost!");
}
```

Here `choices.indexOf(computerChoice)` finds the current positions of the computer's choice in the list. It add's one to find the next element in the list and uses the remainder operator (`% 3`) to make sure that if the next index is higher than the last element in the list, it flips back to the first element.